# How can you loop through python directories and stop once at root

Tags: python, working-directory

In Python, I'm using a `while` loop to test whether the CWD is a git repository. If it's not, the CWD is changed (`..`) and tested again.

If a git repository is found then the function works as expected. However, if no git repository is found, the `while` loop keeps going because `os.chdir('..')` doesn't generate an error, even if the CWD is at `/`.

```
def get_git_repo():
    path = os.getcwd()
    original_path = path
    is_git_repo = False
    while not is_git_repo:
        try:
            repo = git.Repo(path).git_dir
            is_git_repo = True
        except git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError:
            is_git_repo = False
            path = os.chdir('..')
    os.chdir(original_path)
    return repo
```

To try and fix this, I added a test to check if the CWD is `/`, but that doesn't work and the `while` loop still carries on forever.

How can I bail out of the function once the CWD is `/`, and is not a git repository?

```
def get_git_repo():
    ...
        except git.exc.InvalidGitRepositoryError:
            is_git_repo = False
            if not path == '/':
                path = os.chdir('..')
            else:
                raise Exception("Unable to discover path to git repository.")
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem of your code is that `os.chdir('..')` return `None`, not the current path.

You need to get the current dir after the change:

```
os.chdir('..')
path = os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you - that was indeed my problem.